# GamePieces are spawned even though Coroutine (containig Instantiate()) is not starting in Update in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation, coroutine

I want to limit the spawn of game pieces. `PiecesOnBoard` gets the number of existing `GamePieces`.  `maxSpawns` is statically set to a number which should act as the maximum allowed number of GamePieces currently existing.

Now, the problem is that game pieces get spawned anyhow despite the `freeSpawnSpotsAvailable` condition.

Below are some corresponding code and console outputs.

```
void Update()
{
    if (groundPlacement.GroundSet())
    {
        CheckSpawnSpots();

        Debug.Log("FreeSpawnSpotsAvailable: " + freeSpawnSpotsAvailable + "\n" 
            + gameManager.PiecesOnGround.Length + " PiecesOnGround\n"
            + maxSpawns + " maxSpawns\n"
            + (maxSpawns - gameManager.PiecesOnGround.Length) + " free spawn spots");

        if (freeSpawnSpotsAvailable)
        {
            Debug.Log("start spawn");
            StartCoroutine(SpawnRandomGamePieces());
        }
    }
}


private IEnumerator SpawnRandomGamePieces()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(2f, waitSpawnTime));

    GamePiece spawned = Instantiate<GamePiece>(RandomGamePiece(gamePieces), RandomPosition(), Quaternion.identity);
}


private void CheckSpawnSpots()
{
    int freeSpots = maxSpawns - gameManager.PiecesOnGround.Length;
    if (freeSpots > 0)
    {
        freeSpawnSpotsAvailable = true;
    }
    else
    {
        freeSpawnSpotsAvailable = false;
    }
}
```

Exemplary output when game is run (this is a later output, therefore the `PiecesOnGround` has a much higher number):

```
FreeSpawnSpotsAvailable: False
352 PiecesOnGround
10 maxSpawns
-342 free spawn spots
SpawnObjects:Update()
```

I know the Coroutine is not run when `freeSpawnSpotsAvailable = false` since the debug line `Debug.Log("start spawn")` is not printed in the console.
But somehow game pieces get spawned anyhow (and I feel like they are every Update frame) but I don't know why since I don't Instantiate/call this Coroutine elsewhere.

But I also realize now, that even if the Coroutine is started it does not spawn the game pieces (`PiecesOnGround` does not change).
Some console output:

```
FreeSpawnSpotsAvailable: True
8 PiecesOnGround
10 maxSpawns
2 free spawn spots
SpawnObjects:Update()

start spawn
SpawnObjects:Update()

timeLeftInRound: 7, RoundTimerOver: False
GameManager:Update()

FreeSpawnSpotsAvailable: True
8 PiecesOnGround
10 maxSpawns
2 free spawn spots
SpawnObjects:Update()

start spawn
SpawnObjects:Update()
```

I don't get where the spawns are coming from.

**UPDATE:**

I tried moving the conditional test into the Coroutine instead of in the Update:

```
void Update()
{
    if (groundPlacement.GroundSet())
    {
        CheckSpawnSpots();

        Debug.Log("FreeSpawnSpotsAvailable: " + freeSpawnSpotsAvailable + "\n"
            + gameManager.PiecesOnGround.Length + " PiecesOnGround\n"
            + maxSpawns + " maxSpawns\n"
            + (maxSpawns - gameManager.PiecesOnGround.Length) + " free spawn spots");

        StartCoroutine(SpawnRandomGamePieces());
    }
}


private IEnumerator SpawnRandomGamePieces()
{
    Debug.Log("s");
    if (freeSpawnSpotsAvailable)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(2f, waitSpawnTime));

        GamePiece spawned = Instantiate<GamePiece>(RandomGamePiece(gamePieces), RandomPosition(), Quaternion.identity);
        Debug.Log("insantiated at: " + spawned.gameObject.transform.position);
    }
}
```

Now, I get following console output:

```
FreeSpawnSpotsAvailable: False
300 PiecesOnGround
10 maxSpawns
-290 free spawn spots
Spawner:Update()

s
<SpawnRandomGamePieces>d__16:MoveNext()
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)
Spawner:Update()

insantiated at: (-0.30, -0.42, 0.84)
<SpawnRandomGamePieces>d__16:MoveNext()
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)

timeLeftInRound: 2, RoundTimerOver: False
GameManager:Update()

FreeSpawnSpotsAvailable: False
302 PiecesOnGround
10 maxSpawns
-292 free spawn spots
Spawner:Update()
```

`PiecesOnGround` is updated in the Update funtion of my GameManager script through following code (code extract):

```
    public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
       public GamePiece[] PiecesOnGround { get => piecesOnGround; set => piecesOnGround = value; }

       void Update()
       {
           PiecesOnGround = FindObjectsOfType<GamePiece>(); //update
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if (freeSpawnSpotsAvailable)` test is in the wrong place. It is `true`, starts a spawn, then waits for two seconds. All that time more spawns are started ([framrate] will begin every second). By the time it actually spawns it would be `false`, but your coroutine doens't care.

A simple workaround to fix your problem would be to move your test to the place it's actually relevant

```cs
private IEnumerator SpawnRandomGamePieces()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(2f, waitSpawnTime));
    
    CheckSpawnSpots();
    if (freeSpawnSpotsAvailable)
        GamePiece spawned = Instantiate<GamePiece>(RandomGamePiece(gamePieces), RandomPosition(), Quaternion.identity);
}
```

---

But an actual fix would be to change your design. The way you are updating your `freeSpawnSpotsAvailable` is inneficient, and this would still run far more coroutines than are actually needed.

However, an actual solution would look something like this.

```cs
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GamePiece[] peicesOnGroundCache = null;
    public GamePiece[] PiecesOnGround => peicesOnGroundCache ??= FindObjectsOfType<GamePiece>(); // return cached value if exists, otherwise get value

    // IMPORTANT to call this whenever a price is removed too. 
    // This could be a part of the OnDestory callback, or registered as they are created
    public void MarkPeicesOnGroundCacheAsDirty() => peicesOnGroundCache = null;

    // if possible, only spawn GamePeices thorugh this function, 
    // otherwise call MarkPeicesOnGroundCacheAsDirty whenever you spawn them
    public GamePeice SpawnNewGamePeice(GamePeice gamePeice, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation 
    {
        var peice = Instantiate<GamePeice>(gamePeice, position, rotation);
        MarkPeicesOnGroundCacheAsDirty();

        return peice;
    }
}
```

Then in your spawner class

```cs
private Coroutine spawnCoroutine = null;

void Update()
{
    if (groundPlacement.GroundSet())
    {
        if(spawnCoroutine != null)
            return; // already spawning :)
    
        var peicesToSpawn = int freeSpots = maxSpawns - gameManager.PiecesOnGround.Length; // this is cached so fast
    
        if(peicesToSpan > 0)
            spawnCoroutine = StartCoroutine(SpawnRandomGamePieces(peicesToSpawn));
    }
}
private IEnumerator SpawnRandomGamePieces(int peicesToSpawn)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(2f, waitSpawnTime));

    for(int i = 0; i < peicesToSpawn; i++) // spawn enough right away
    {
        var _ gameManager.SpawnNewGamePeice(RandomGamePeice(), RandomPosition(), Quaternion.Identity);      
        
        // uncomment if you want only one to spawn per frame
        //yield return null;
    }
    spawnCoroutine = null;
}
```

This should give you the behaviour you are looking for while being a little cleaner and better for performance.

(note the check on coroutine being null could be replaced by a bool flag if you prefer)

Comment: I also tried moving the conditional test as you did above, but it did not change anything. I put in that code and the console output in the edit

Comment: Not quite, look at my code again and see the difference. Your edit is functionally identical as it was before. The test has to be *after* the delay. Not before

Comment: In general using `FindObjectsOfType<GamePiece>();` in `Update` is a terrible idea! Rather make your coroutine "block" a slot right away, inform the manager thingy that somthing was spawned and keep count **event driven** rather than poll checking your entire scen for changes every frame

Comment: @Jay that would indeed be a "workaround" .. I would recommend to rather fix the underlying issues in the software design in the first place

Comment: an alternative to at least avoid concurrent routines might be to add a simple `bool SpawnRandomGamePiecesAlreadyRunning;` flag you set to `true` immediately then the routine starts and check additionally still looks quite inefficient though .. you could even only run one single coroutine with a while loop instead of merging `Update` and routines

Comment: @derHugo fair call, added a proper solutiuon. More optimisations always possible but I'd call this okay

Comment: @Jay I think you still would need to reset `spawnCoroutine = null` at the end of the routine ... unfortunately afaik even a finished routine is not `null` ^^

Comment: @Jay, you are right, thanks! But why is it a problem when the test ist before the delay?

Comment: @derHugo how do i count event driven with another coroutine? not quite sure how to do this practically. Do you mean to move the `FindObjectsOfType<GamePiece>();` into a Coroutine in my `GameManager` script? ?

Comment: @buolou you could either have public methods for `AddedPeice` and `RemovedPeice` which are called each time a script adds or removes a peice, or you could have public events for `OnPeiceCreated` and `OnPeiceDestroyed` that could be listened for by your `GameManager`, which would either add or subrtract from the peices array/count